# predict.MCMCglmm error -- giving broad non-granular values

Tags: r, bayesian, predict, mixed-models, mcmc

I'm using the `MCMCglmm` function in its package to create a mixed-effects model for three-level categorical model.  The goal is to get probabilities of each of the three classes in `response` for each row of data in the 5000 row `test_week` test set.

```
prior6 <- list(R=list(V=diag(2), nu=0.0001),
               G=list(G1=list(V=diag(4), nu=0.0001, alpha.mu=rep(0,4), alpha.V=diag(4) * 25),
                      G2=list(V=diag(1), nu=0.0001, alpha.mu=rep(0,1), alpha.V=diag(1) * 25),
                      G3=list(V=diag(2), nu=0.0001, alpha.mu=rep(0,2), alpha.V=diag(2) * 25),
                      G4=list(V=diag(1), nu=0.0001, alpha.mu=rep(0,1), alpha.V=diag(1) * 25),
                      G5=list(V=diag(2), nu=0.0001, alpha.mu=rep(0,2), alpha.V=diag(2) * 25),
                      G6=list(V=diag(1), nu=0.0001, alpha.mu=rep(0,1), alpha.V=diag(1) * 25)))

mix_mod_fit6 <- MCMCglmm(response ~ 1 + x + y + z, random=~us(1 + x + y + z):a + 
                           us(1):d + us(1 + x):b + us(1):e + us(1 + z):c + us(1):f, 
                         rcov=~ us(trait):units, prior=prior6, family='categorical', 
                         data=train_weeks_sample1, nitt=3850, thin=45, burnin=2500)

mixed_final_predictions6 <- predict.MCMCglmm(mix_mod_fit6, test_week, 
                                             type='response', interval='prediction')
```

The issue arises with the predict function, returning a 10000x1 matrix of numbers that very roughly mirror the probabilities of the 2nd and 3rd levels in `response` (the first 5000 rows corresponding to the 2nd level and the following 5000 to the 3rd level) after I split them into a 5000x2 matrix.  I can then backsolve to get the predictions for the 1st level, but the predictions are problematic.  They only predict in multiples of 1/30 as shown below (and also illustrated in the histograms in the picture).

```
temp6
                 0 0.0333333333333333 0.0666666666666667                0.1  0.133333333333333  0.166666666666667 
              7935               3914               2199               1901               1883               2173 
               0.2  0.233333333333333  0.266666666666667                0.3  0.333333333333333  0.366666666666667 
              2257               2198               1991               1703               1465               1184 
               0.4  0.433333333333333  0.466666666666667                0.5  0.533333333333333  0.566666666666667 
               987                756                527                410                268                164 
               0.6  0.633333333333333  0.666666666666667                0.7 
                98                 35                 24                  6
```

Any insight or examples on how the `predict.MCMCglmm` function works, how to receive predictions more granular than just thirtieths, as well as predictions for all three levels rather than just two would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Note: The prior's V values were specifically selected to match the element sizes in the `MCMCglmm` call, and cannot be changed.  However, altering the value of `nu` has no effect on the predictions, nor does ommitting `alpha.mu` and `alpha.V`.

*Current results vs ideal results distribution example:*

[image: Current results vs ideal results distribution example]